# Posting to Express router from Vue.JS

Tags: node.js, http, express, vue.js

I am trying to post data from a vue.js front end to my express/node backend. The POST seems to go through but on the backend I'm just getting an undefined empty array.

Front End:

`main.js`

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    guests: [],
    code: '',
    showGuests: true
},
methods: {
    saveGuests: function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/api/rsvp/' + this.code,
            data: this.guests,
            success: function() {
                this.showGuests = false;
                // do more stuff to handle submission
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    },
...
```

Back End:

`app.js`

```
//body parser
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

//express
var express = require('express');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

// create a new express server
var app = express();

var rsvp = cloudant.db.use('rsvp');

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//endpoint to post rsvp details
app.post('/api/rsvp/:code', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('POST request received successfully')
});

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    // print a message when the server starts listening
    console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

The `guests` array is populated by another function which I've omitted. It looks like this:

```
[{
   fullName: "john smith",
   rsvpStatus: "Not Responded"
},{
   fullName: "Mr Stack Overflow",
   rsvpStatus: "Yes"
}]
```

the `console.log` on the node server is just giving me this after a POST attempt:

```
{ undefined: [ '', '' ] }
```

Any help would be great. Maybe there's something I need do with Vue data bindings before I post them? I'm new to Vue so almost certainly doing something wrong.

Thanks :D

Comment: Is your `guests` array on frontend side filled with data before your post request?

Comment: Yep, I've logged that during the POST request and it shows data on the front end#

Answer (score 2):

Managed to answer this myself. Basically for some reason using jQuery POST within Vue was messing things up. I added the ["vue-resource" plugin](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) for vue and then was able to do the same POST using:

```
this.$http.post('url', data);
```